# How to edit objects within an initialized array of class instances in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-hooks, initialization

I am working on a React application where I have an array of objects stored as a state using the useState function. These objects are instances of a class called Journey, which I use to parse data coming from a database. Occasionally, I need to edit the properties of these objects after the state has been set.

Here is an example of my current setup:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const initialJourneysFromDB = [
    { idDB: 1, vehicleDB: "Car", dateDB: "2023-06-01", childrenDB: 2 , adultsDB: 1},
    { idDB: 2, vehicleDB: "Bus", dateDB: "2023-06-02", childrenDB: 3 , adultsDB: 3},
    { idDB: 1, vehicleDB: "Car", dateDB: "2023-06-05", childrenDB: 1 , adultsDB: 2},
    { idDB: 3, vehicleDB: "Jet", dateDB: "2023-06-03", childrenDB: 0 , adultsDB: 2},
];

// The class is very large and complex
// - it has more than a hundred parameter values all sent as a single object and obtained internally through dot notation
// - the values are renamed in this class as its main function is to parse the data from the database
// - some information is lost in the parsing
// - some values have to be calculated after the initialization as they require the complete list of parsed objects to obtain
class Journey {
    constructor(params) {
        this.id = params.idDB;
        this.vehicle = params.vehicleDB;
        this.date = params.dateDB;
        this.passengers = params.childrenDB + params.adultsDB; // the numbers of children and adults are lost
        this.pastJourneysForSameVehicle = null; // a list that will be calculated after initialization
    }

    setPastJourneys(journeys) {
        this.pastJourneysForSameVehicle = journeys.filter(
            journey => journey.vehicle === this.vehicle && journey.date < this.date
        );
    }
}

function App() {
    
    const [journeys, setJourneys] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const parsedJourneyList = initialJourneysFromDB.map(journeyData => {
            return new Journey(journeyData);
        })
        parsedJourneyList.forEach(journeyData => {
            journeyData.setPastJourneys(parsedJourneyList); // Set pastJourneysForSameVehicle value after initialization
        })
        setJourneys(parsedJourneyList)
    }, [])

    return (
        // ...JSX
    );
}
```

I am looking for the best approach to edit the properties of objects within the journeys state while following good practices. The problem I have is I cannot seem to find a way to edit the properties of the class without either destroying the class instance or changing the React states value without using the React state setter.

Here are the options I've considered so far:

1. Editing the objects directly: One approach would be to edit the properties of the objects directly using an external function or a setter method. However, this goes against the principle of not modifying the initial state without using the setState function, which is not ideal when working with React states.

```js
const modifyPropertyDirectly = () => {
    const updatedJourneys = [...journeys];
    const journeyToUpdate = updatedJourneys.find(journey => journey.id === 1)
    journeyToUpdate.date = "2023-06-04";
    setJourneys(updatedJourneys);
};
```

2. Recreating the object: Another approach would be to recreate the object with the edited property value. This approach aligns with the principle of not editing the state object directly but comes with the drawback of destroying the original class instance.

```js
const recreateObjectWithModifiedProperty = () => {
    const updatedJourneys = journeys.map(journey => {
        const newObj = {...journey}
        if (journey.id === 1) {
            newObj.date = "2023-06-04"
        }
        return newObj;
    });
    setJourneys(updatedJourneys);
};
```

Considering these points and any other I may not have considered, how could I go about editing the properties of objects within an initialized array of class instances in a React state? How can I efficiently update specific properties of the Journey objects without violating good practices?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on the most appropriate and maintainable way to handle this scenario. Thank you!

Comment: You raise valid concerns about methods that you have listed. Is there a reason you are not just editing the data in the database and then refetching?

Comment: Hello @Stitt, good question. The array of objects mentioned is very large and the objects themselves have a lot of values; on the other hand, in most cases only a single value for a single object is edited at a time, so it would seem very ineficient to reobtain all values from the database every time an edit is made. This could also potencially increase cloud costs and server saturation, as well as cause lag as some users have a bad internet connection. Feel free to ask if you have any additional doubts.

Comment: Okay, what database framework are using. Apollo GraphQL (where my experience is) supports a cache & partial re-fetching option which will only re-fetch what was been modified, which sounds like a suitable option for your usecase.

Comment: I'm definitely looking into that. It seems like it could be the solution to our problem. We currently use https and socket.io to connect the front and back end, and knex.js to connect the backend to our MSSQL database.